# Handling Multiple Collisions for 2d Platformer

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics

I am looking for ideas on how to handle multiple collisions. For example: currently if my player character lands on an enemy tagged object, a raycast handles collision detection for a seamless kill.

I like how this works, as it is similar to 2dCollision detection thru using a trigger enter method, however it enables me to fine tune the distance, so that the collision can occur just before the 2 sprites actually overlap.

My idea, for the same enemy to kill the player, would be to implement another raycast, 1 at the front of the enemy sprite, and one behind it. It those raycasts hit the player, the player dies.

My question is whether or not that is the most effective method. I have yet to implement it, as I would like some input from others before potentially wasting my time.

Comment: It sounds like you have a workable idea. [My general advice in such situations is to try it](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2808/39518). If it works as you need, you can immediately proceed to your next feature, without waiting for Internet randos like us to opine on it (and possibly give you bad advice). If it *doesn't* work as you need, you'll be able to *identify a specific problem with it*, and then ask a question here about how to solve that problem. This generally gets more useful answers, because it gets to the heart of what the feature should/shouldn't do to serve your game.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I usually try to take that approach, but will be consumed at work for another few hours. Wanted to put the idea out there and see if there was any input. Thank you for your insight, I appreciate it!